# How to set "focus" on firefox?

Tags: jquery

I have js:

```
$(document).on('focus', '.uiopis', function() {
    $(this).removeClass("textareaBlur").addClass("textareaFocus");  
}).on('blur', '.uiopis', function() {  
    $(this).removeClass("textareaFocus").addClass("textareaBlur");   
});
```

and html:

```
<div>
    <form>
        <textarea class="uiopis" id="os{{ us.id }}" name="os{{ us.id }}">{{ us }}</textarea>
    </form>
</div>
```

but this not working on firefox, why?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/owilum/1/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Focus/blur events won't bubble, so you'll need to attach your handlers like this:

```
$('.uiopis').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).removeClass("textareaBlur").addClass("textareaFocus");  
}).on('blur', function() {  
    $(this).removeClass("textareaFocus").addClass("textareaBlur");   
});
```

Assuming `.uiopis` is dynamically generated (since you've used delegation in your code), you'll have to add the handler after `.uiopis` has been added to the DOM.